# Assign a specific bg color to an image in an array (Javascript Only)

Tags: javascript, arrays, background-color

I'm using a script to generate a random header image, but I would like to be able to assign a specific background color behind each header when it loads. I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve this using only Javascript (unable to use any other language, unfortunately.)

This is the random image script I'm using. For each of the 6 images, I'd like to assign a specific backgroundColor. I've tried a few things but nothing seems to be working. Any suggestions?:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function random_imglink(){
var myimages=new Array()

myimages[1]="image1.gif"
myimages[2]="image2.gif"
myimages[3]="image3.gif"
myimages[4]="image4.gif"
myimages[5]="image5.gif"
myimages[6]="image6.gif"

var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length)
if (ry==0)
ry=1
document.write('<img src="'+myimages[ry]+'" class="header">')
}
random_imglink()

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I think though you'll need a container div to wrap your image in for the background color. (I assume these are transparent gifs...)

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f4drr6kL/3/

```
var myimages = new Array();

function random_imglink(){
    myimages[0]= { 
        img   : "http://info.eps.surrey.ac.uk/logos/transbugs.gif", 
        color : "red" 
    }; 
    myimages[1]= { 
         img   : "http://info.eps.surrey.ac.uk/logos/transbugs.gif", 
         color : "blue" 
    };
    myimages[2]= { 
         img   : "http://info.eps.surrey.ac.uk/logos/transbugs.gif", 
         color : "green" 
    };
    myimages[3]= { 
          img   : "http://info.eps.surrey.ac.uk/logos/transbugs.gif", 
          color : "yellow" 
     };
    myimages[4]= { 
         img   : "http://info.eps.surrey.ac.uk/logos/transbugs.gif", 
         color : "orange" 
    };
    myimages[5]= { 
        img   : "http://info.eps.surrey.ac.uk/logos/transbugs.gif", 
        color : "cyan" 
    };

    var ry = Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length);
    document.getElementById("a_div").innerHTML = '<img src="' + myimages[ry].img + '" class="header" style="background-color:' + myimages[ry].color + ';">';
}
random_imglink();
```

Comment: This seems to be causing it to actually display the number of the image about to be randomly generated in a pop-up alert before it loads. I can't seem to get it to stop doing that, nor can I get it to properly call the right colors with the right images.

Comment: Okay, so I realized that the alert is actually what's displaying the pop-up, (duh), and I used that to verify that it's actually calling the right background color with the right image (I did alert(myimages[ry].color); to verify) but it's not displaying that background color in the div that the image is occupying.

Comment: Back again - fun realizing things as you go! I guess I should have been more clear in my intent earlier (if anyone is still looking at this) - what I'm actually targeting is the div the images are sitting in. So, I have header images, about 800px wide and a 100% width header div. The bg colors are changing now, but they're exactly the size of the image, but doesn't actually help much, as they need to be 100% width, ie: the div.)

Comment: Okay, easy enough. Then you just do document.getElementById with the id of the div you want to target. If you found my answer helpful, you could even upvote it! ;)